# Rings and some of their properties

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am studying for an exam and was wondering if anyone could explain some of the reasoning being the proofs of the following properties:

Let R be a ring with $a,b\in R$. Then

1. $a0=0a=0$
2. $a(-b)=(-a)b=-ab$
3. $(-a)(-b)=ab$

Proof 1:

$a0=a(0+0)=a0+a0$ hence $a0=0$

I don't really understand why $a0+a0$ proves that $a0=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:** I should have asked whether your definition of a ring include the existence of the multiplicative identity called $1$. (This is called a 'ring with unity' to distinguish from a 'ring', since some textbooks do not assume that there is a $1$.) But the properties that you are asked to prove still hold even if there is no $1$.

$a0 = a0 + a0 \implies 0 = a0$ by subtracting $a0$ from both sides.

Without assuming that the unit $1$ exists, we can still do the same argument:

$$a(-b)+ab = a(-b + b) = a0 = 0$$

Then add $-ab$ to both sides:
$$a(-b) = -ab.$$

Showing that $(-a)b = ab$ is similar.

To show that $(-a)(-b) = ab$, do a similar computation:
$$(-a)(-b) + (-ab) = (-a)(-b) + (-a)b = (-a)(-b+b) = (-a)0 = 0$$ where we used property (2) to write $-ab = (-a)b$. Then add $+ab$ to both sides:
$$(-a)(-b) = ab.$$

Comment: So you can subtract even though subtraction isn't a property that defines a ring?

Comment: I should have been more precise, sorry. Subtracting $x$ means adding $-x$, the additive inverse of $x$.

Comment: @USC I edited this a few times. Hopefully this presentation will be more clear.